# How to Backup Database with Vb.Net without SSMS?

Tags: database, vb.net, backup

Currently I used to back up my files in the way that, when user click on Backup the program will ask,

> To Backup you must close your current session. This application will be closed now. Do you want to continue?

So the application will be closed and a new application will be launch in which if you click Backup it will copy the *.mdf* File and the *.ldf* File

|

But I have read in many pages that 'Copying the *.mdf* File and the *.ldf* File' is the unsafest way, so is there any other way to do Backup other than using SSMS because I want the user to be able to Backup within the Application.

|

Current code:

```
Sub Backup()

    Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=BQDB;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "Backup database BQDB To Disk='C:\Users\Zulfikar\BQBackup.BAK'"
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

|

[Error Message Using Justin's Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JibkQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to see a performance boost when using SqlCommands to backup databases.

```
      Sub Backup()

               Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=DATASOURCE;initial catalog=NAME OF DATABASE;Integrated Security=True")
               Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

                    Try                         
                        con.Open() 
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        cmd.CommandText = "Backup database BQDB To Disk='C:\Users\Zulfikar\BQBackup.BAK'"
                        cmd.Connection = con
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    End Try
                End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Justin Woodmancy ,
I am having 2 problem while trying your code...  |   Problem #1: My database name is BQDB so how can I replace this with your code? Is it like this? --- `cmd.CommandText = "Backup database BQDB To Disk='C:\Users\Zulfikar\BQBackup.BAK'"`

Comment: Problem #2: When I tried your code the error I get is: **Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts** , so what the problem and what is the fix?

Comment: Check my edit. It sounds like you don't have your connection string to the database set up.

Comment: Hi
How can I find my **data source** , I mean what should I replace with 'DATASOURCE' and the 'Name Of Database' is the name of the  `.mdf` file right?